# Ubuntu Sound only works through headphone front panel - HDMI not detected and green rear jack selects wrong option!

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I have a gigabyte  GA-78LMT-USB3 motherboard, and Ubuntu 18.04.
The HDMI and rear panel line output both work fine in Windows, but they don't work in Ubuntu.
Ubuntu sound output only shows headphone or SPDIF, neither of which sends sound to the HDMI. I tried common stuff on the forums, force reloaded alsa, but HDMI did not appear as an option, still didn't work.
Instead I plugged a 2 channel analogue jack into the green line out socket at the rear, but that didn't work either. When the jack is inserted pulse audio mixer changes from stereo 2 channel to surround sound. No sound comes out of the speakers. If I half remove the jack, pulse audio changes back to stereo and I can hear left or right channel through the half connected audio jack.
Finally, I connected a PC front panel to my motherboard. Ubuntu sends stereo sound to this headphone jack with no problems.
Please help me fix the output to HDMI and green rear audio jack :)